# Significance of differences in answers to vague questions

Tags: statistical-significance

Participants in an experiment were divided in “Truth-judgers” and “Falsity-judgers”. The former were asked “When is it true to say that a man is tall [cm]?” while the latter were asked: “When is it false to say that a man is tall [cm]?”

How could the hypothesis that average estimates of “Truth-judgers” are significantly larger than those of “Falsity-judgers” be analyzed with the obtained data?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have two independent samples (assuming no person were in both groups, and one answer per person).  Your null hypothesis is "the means are equal", the alternative hypothesis that means are not equal.  You should plot the two histograms (or some dot-plot) on the same axis, and maybe a t-test or Wilcoxon test.